# Google App Engine ignoring Springboot application properties

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, properties

I'm deploying a pretty basic web app to Google App Engine.  I'm using Springboot and I can run the app locally just fine, but when I deploy to Google, the App Engine does not start up the instance.  I have a Cloud SQL datasource being configured on startup.

I have the cloud sql configuration properties configured in src/main/resources/application.properties. It seems that App Engine cannot find these properties so it is failing to properly setup the Cloud sql datasource.

Has anyone ran into this issue?  It seems like something so basic.  I'm hoping a second pair of eyes and brain can shed some light.  Thanks!

EDIT:

Thank you for your responses.  Here is a snippet of the properties file:

```
#################### DATABASE SETTINGS
#POSTGRES connection parameters
application.postgres.driver-name=org.postgresql.Driver
application.postgres.url=jdbc:postgresql://<url>:5432/<db>
application.postgres.max-pool-size=5
application.postgres.min-pool-size=1
application.postgres.connection-wait-time-seconds=60
application.postgres.schema=dev
application.postgres.preparedstatement-cache-queries-size=256
application.postgres.preparedstatement-cache-size=500
application.postgres.preparedstatement-cache-sql-limit=5
application.postgres.preparedthreshold=5
application.postgres.ssl.enabled=true

#################### GOOGLE CLOUD SETTINGS
application.google.project.id=<our project>
application.google.project.region=us-central1
application.google.project.cloud.sql.instance.name=<cloud sql instance>
application.google.project.cloud.sql.instance=${application.google.project.id}:${application.google.project.region}:${application.google.project.cloud.sql.instance.name}
```

I  have this located in the src/main/resources (as usual).

I've tried running in a flex and standard environment.  I wanted to make sure one or the other wasn't causing the issue.

my appengine-web.xml looked like this for the standard env:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>my app name</application>
  <service>my service name</service>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>

</appengine-web-app>
```

And here was my yaml file for the flex environment (nothing fancy. pretty bare bones setup.):

```
runtime: java
env: flex  
service: my service name

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
```

I would post the stack traces, but they are not very helpful.  It's basically just the error that I cannot load my cloud sql datasource (ie: because it's not picking up the properties).  If I hardcode the values in my Config class that initializes the datasource, it works so I can definitely tell it's just not wanting to pick up the application.properties).

My app setup is typical:

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/main/webapp
*src/main/appengine (yaml location for flex env)
```

Note: I'm attempting to pass the postgres (ie: cloud sql) username and password in my maven deploy command:

mvn package -DskipTests appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.projectId=myproject -Dapp.deploy.version=1 -Dapplication.postgres.username= -Dapplication.postgres.password=

Comment: Can you please attach the complete stack trace.?

Comment: Are you using Standard,Flexible or custom environment? Can you edit your answer providing some information like your pom.xml and anything that could help to reproduce your issue? 
I have done the same concept to Standard environment and also in flexible. You can follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-spring-petclinic-on-app-engine-cloudsql) of Google's community post.

Comment: As @TasosV commented, following the documentation should be working fine for you. I have followed this guide and I managed to launch a Google App Engine instance with Spring and connected to Cloud SQL. It will be good if you could provide your application.properties file so we can help you with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. just add the following in app.yml
resources:
cpu: 2
memory_gb: 3
disk_size_gb: 10
volumes:
- volume_type: tmpfs
size_gb: 2
name: ramdisk1